# Timed sound effect happening twice via Handler

Tags: android

My activity plays a specific sound effect once every second. 
The following code works, however there is a bug: occasionally the sound is played TWICE every second. This only happens every once in a while (once every 10-20 attempts). When it happens, the double sound occurs for the entire run of the activity, start to finish. So, if I see the activity started without the bug, it stays that way for the entire run of the activity.

Here's the relevant code - what's the problem with it? Thank you!

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();       
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.post(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {        
    // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    super.onPause();
}

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        PlayTick();                     
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

    public void PlayTick() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
float actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution - seems it's a known SoundPool bug, it sometimes plays the effect twice. I used a .wav file; converting the file to .ogg seems to resolve the issue.